# Better way to kill all processes with a handle to some file

Tags: files, kill, process-management

This kills every process with a handle to file /foo/bar (in bash):

```
 lsof /foo/bar 2>&1 | grep "/foo/bar" | sed "s/  */\\t/g" | cut -f 2 | while read PID; do kill $PID; done
```

This does not seem like such an uncommon task that there wouldn't be an easier solution, so I'm wondering if there's something like `killall` or a switch to `kill` that I've missed which does the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what `-t` is for. The man page even suggests you'd use that for `kill`.

```
lsof -t /some/file | xargs kill
```

Traditionally (before the `lsof` days), you'd use:

```
fuser /some/file 2> /dev/null | xargs kill
```

for that.

Some `fuser` implementations, like the one found on most Linux-based operating systems , Solaris or recent FreeBSDs can even do the killing by themselves:

```
fuser -k /some/file
```

However note that they send a SIGKILL, not SIGTERM. You can choose a different signal with `-TERM` with some implementations and `-s TERM` with others.

Comment: Nice - also, I didn't know about xargs.